# How can i post data using this code below and also tell user to wait while sending message

Tags: vb4android

Iam currently using b4a for android

here is the error which comes

```
enter code here
 ',' expected.`enter code here`


enter code here
Dim j As HttpJob
            j.Initialize("", Me)
            j.PostString($"http://kccug.com/KabojjaApp/RecieveSMS.ashx?customerId=${act}&s=${edtMessage.Text}&d=${getdate(DateTime.Now)}&id=${NewID}&ph=${phone}&f=${sx}"$ )
            Wait For (j) JobDone(j As HttpJob)
            If j.Success Then
                Log(j.GetString)
            End If

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `j.PostString` which sends a post request. However, you are not using it correctly. `j.PostString` requires a second parameter: the post data. B4A expects you to put in a comma and the second paramter after the url, but you are only giving 1 parameter (the url) to the function. However, looking at your URL, it seems like your backend is handling stuff through GET requests only anyway, not POST. So really, what you *should* be using is `j.Download`. Try this code:

```
Dim j As HttpJob
j.Initialize("", Me)
j.Download($"http://kccug.com/KabojjaApp/RecieveSMS.ashx?customerId=${act}&s=${edtMessage.Text}&d=${getdate(DateTime.Now)}&id=${NewID}&ph=${phone}&f=${sx}"$)
Wait For (j) JobDone(j As HttpJob)
If j.Success Then
    Log(j.GetString)
End If
```

It's exactly the same, but it uses `Download` instead of `PostString`.